# Why I can't use GPU when I training yolov5&yolov6 on my own dataset?

Tags: pytorch, yolov5

As I describe in the title, I can not use GPU to accelerate my training process both in yolov5 and yolov6.
My torch version is 1.12, the output of torch.cuda.is_available() is Ture.
Every configration I have done are all follow the Tutorials in their offical github.
By the way, a few time ago I can train yolov5 and accelerate with GPU successfully, how oddly it is?
The training config and gpu usage snapshot is attached.
[gpu usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkK3e.png)
[training config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48Z3U.png)

Comment: Which command have you used to run this script?

Comment: I run this script in pycharm all the configration is setted according fig2.

Comment: By the way, the configration I have used is not changed. I just change the batch size and epoch, I think this is not related to this issue.

Comment: When did you check the gpu usage exactly?

Comment: During the training porcess.

Comment: And about a moth ago, it runs normally.

Comment: Please look at it throughout training (make sure the PyTorch process is still running when you check it). You can `nvidia-smi -l 1` to refresh your GPU usage output in the cmd line.

Comment: I use the command `watch -n 1 nvidia-smi`  to check my gpu usage.